# Open URL in new firefox window not tab in a bash script

Tags: scripting, firefox, window

I want to open a URL in Firefox always in a new Window and not in a new tab.

It is on my raspberry PI on iceweasel and I just can't find a soultion for my problem.

What do I have:

```
firefox -private-window https://myurl.com/
```

Is there any Parameter I can set that it open in a new window or do I have to edit the iceweasel settings?

Comment: Did you go through the options of `firefox --help`?

Comment: Yes and there is the --new-window Parameter but this sin't working it is still opening in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use the option --new-window  with firefox:

```
firefox --new-window  https://myurl.com/
```

Comment: Yes i ahve tried this one but it just didn't wokred for me...

Comment: could you send me your Firefox version?

Comment: My currently installed Version is: 31.5.3esr-1~deb7u1+rpi1